# How could I refresh the following the php file? (Without the page reloading)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cpu

I've been playing around creating a control panel for gameservers, however I would love to show the user some CPU percentages. I totally can, but it doesn't update itself automatically. Here are my Codes
**Note:** This is not a working code, I mean it works, but only if you have load.php, which totally works, so I'm not going to bother showing it, it basically returns a number + %, to be able to modify the width of the progress bar.
What I want is pretty simple, **I want the bar to update itself automatically.** I just don't know why my code doesn't work.

```
<?php include '../includes/kezelohead.php'; ?>
<?php 
include 'load.php';
//echo $cpu;
?>
<h5>Processzor Hasznalat</h5>

<div class="progress progress-striped" id="prog">
  <div id='bar' class='progress-bar progress-bar-custom active' role='progressbar' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style="width:100%;">
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var interval = setInterval(cpu, 2000);
function cpu() {
  $("#scores").load("load.php #scores");
  var data = <?php echo(json_encode($cpu)); ?>;
  document.getElementById('bar').style.width = data;
  //setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
}
</script>
<div id='scores'>
<?php 
include 'load.php';
//echo $cpu;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up AJAX on the web

Comment: 1) Refresh page through html meta tag. 2) Use AJAX and timer to refresh only data. 3) Web Sockets to push data from server

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! 1. Refreshing the page is not an option when it comes to a realtime CPU usage bar. 2. Well,I'll look it up, and see what I can do about that. 3. Sounds nice, but also pretty hard for a beginner :)

Comment: In your load.php, listen for GET requests and respond with the data, then, with an interval, send a GET request to load.php with jQuery's Ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - Then you can update the DOM with the response.

Comment: Thanks Tom! That's a definitely more helpful than "look up ajax on the web". No offense Riggs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem, with AJAX, so thanks everyone :)
I have used Ajax's load function, like so: `$('#scores').load('load.php');`

Comment: Be sure to [accept your answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as this indicates to others that your problem is solved. You can even do this on [self-answered questions](stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! :) You guys are really helpful! I'll do it asap, but I have to wait two days.